# File upload not working, but fine in Codepen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, file-upload

I'm implementing this codepen I found for a file upload function. It works fine on codepen, however when I actually put it into my own html/css/js setup the file does not upload. I get no file name showing after a file has been selected.
Here is the code from codepen:

```
HTML
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="file-upload">
  <div class="file-select">
    <div class="file-select-button" id="fileName">Choose File</div>
    <div class="file-select-name" id="noFile">No file chosen...</div> 
    <input type="file" name="chooseFile" id="chooseFile">
  </div>
</div>

CSS
body
{
    background-color: black;
}
.file-upload
{
  width: 400px;
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
.file-upload .file-select
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #dce4ec;
    color: #34495e;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
.file-upload .file-select .file-select-button
{
    background: #dce4ec;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.file-upload .file-select .file-select-name
{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.file-upload .file-select:hover
{
    border-color: #34495e;
    moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.file-upload .file-select:hover .file-select-button
{
    background: #34495e;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.file-upload.active .file-select
{
    border-color: #3fa46a;
    moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.file-upload.active .file-select .file-select-button
{
    background: #3fa46a;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.file-upload .file-select input[type=file]
{
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.file-upload .file-select.file-select-disabled
{
    opacity: 0.65;
}
.file-upload .file-select.file-select-disabled:hover
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #dce4ec;
    color: #34495e;
    cursor: default;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
.file-upload .file-select.file-select-disabled:hover .file-select-button
{
    background: #dce4ec;
    color: #666666;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.file-upload .file-select.file-select-disabled:hover .file-select-name
{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

JS
$('#chooseFile').bind('change', function () {
  var filename = $("#chooseFile").val();
  if (/^\s*$/.test(filename)) {
    $(".file-upload").removeClass('active');
    $("#noFile").text("No file chosen..."); 
  }
  else {
    $(".file-upload").addClass('active');
    $("#noFile").text(filename.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "")); 
  }
});
```

I've pasted the exact same code into my html and tried linking the javascript in both head and body. Also tried putting jquery cdn in both head and body. No success.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

******UPDATE******
Thanks for the suggestions guys. I actually tried the it with the CSS turned off and it works fine, which tells me it's nothing to do with the JS. So follow up question, what is it about this CSS that's stopping it from displaying the uploaded file?

Answer (score 0):

You can open up the JavaScript tools in your browser and set a breakpoint on this line:

```
if (/^\s*$/.test(filename)) {
```

Then when the code runs you can see what value 'filename' has and figure out why the regular expression fails, and what it should be.  The regexp you have there looks like it is checking for "a string that starts and ends with 0 or more spaces", so maybe you'll need to check for "filename.length == 0" or "filename === undefined".

You can debug the code in your destination website, but also within Codepen.  It's a little tricky but can inspect your code running inside the pen to get a value for comparison.

If you still need help, please write back with the value of "filename" from your debugger sessions.

[Debugging JS in Chrome tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it don't works in your html site, because the javascript will be executed too early. Wrap your js code into:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Put code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chooseFile").change(function () {
       //your code here
    });
});
```